# Xml + schema in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know about **NSXMLParser**, but I need to use all data in xml-document.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ValidatingXML.html) I read, that **NSXMLParser** supports schema, I am new in iOS developing, can you show me a little example, how I can parse xml-document with schema, like json document to **NSDictionary**:

```
var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:    NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made this new simple and lightweight XML parser for iOS in Swift - [AEXML](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)

You can use it to read XML data like this:

```
let someValue = xmlDocument["element"]["child"]["anotherChild"].value
```

or you can use it to build XML string like this:

```
let document = AEXMLDocument()
let element = document.addChild("element")
element.addChild("child")
document.xmlString // returns XML string of the entire document structure
```

I hope that helps.